# How to join multiple tables in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

how to create view of this query anyone help me please, i want create view of this but its show me error

> Msg 4506, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ordersview, Line 3 Column names
>   in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'ID' in view or
>   function 'ordersview' is specified more than once.

```
CREATE VIEW ordersview
AS
Select * from UserClaimData cd
 Inner join UserClaimDeductions ud on
ud.CLAIMID = cd.ID 
Inner join UserClaimApproval  ua on
ua.CLAIMID = cd.ID  
inner join ClaimDataBreakdown cb on
cb.CLAIMID = cd.ID
inner join  AppExpenseTypes ae on
ae.ID = cb.EXPENSETYPE 
inner join AppNOWTypes an on
ae.ID =  an.EXPENSETYPEID
inner join  AppAreas aa on
aa.ID = cb.AREAID 
inner join AppZones az on
cb.ZONEID = az.ID
inner join AppRegions ar on
ar.ID = cb.REGIONID
```

Comment: Don't just `Select * from ...`. Choose your columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question you've asked is to specifically reference elements from each table; for example:

```
CREATE VIEW ordersview
AS
Select cd.ID AS ID1, ua.ID as ID2, etc... from UserClaimData cd
 Inner join UserClaimDeductions ud on
ud.CLAIMID = cd.ID 
Inner join UserClaimApproval  ua on
ua.CLAIMID = cd.ID  
inner join ClaimDataBreakdown cb on
cb.CLAIMID = cd.ID
inner join  AppExpenseTypes ae on
ae.ID = cb.EXPENSETYPE 
inner join AppNOWTypes an on
ae.ID =  an.EXPENSETYPEID
inner join  AppAreas aa on
aa.ID = cb.AREAID 
inner join AppZones az on
cb.ZONEID = az.ID
inner join AppRegions ar on
ar.ID = cb.REGIONID
```

I would, however, suggest that you don't put such a complex join inside a view.  Consider the columns you want, and perhaps think about a stored procedure, or a table value function.

Answer (score 1):

What part of the error message do you not understand?

You have `select *`, which brings together all columns from all tables.  Just based on the `join` conditions, it is clear that most tables have an `ID` column, so there are multiple columns called `ID`.  `CLAIMID` also seems quite popular.

In general, using `select *` is discouraged.  However, it should not be used for views.  A view should state the columns that it contains:

```
select cd.Id, . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

A view is like a virtual table, So you can't have the same name for 2(or more) columns.

So to avoid this, in your select Query instead of * provide the column names, and if there are 2 columns with the same name and you need them both in the view, give them different alias names.

Suppose you have ColumnA in TableA and TableB and you want them both in the view. Create view like this

```
CREATE VIEW vm_Sample
SELECT 
A.COLUMNA COLUMNA_1,
B.COLUMNA COLUMNA_2 
    FROM TABLEA A INNER JOIN TABLE B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view has more than one column with the same name, and this is causing the error.

- `AppRegions` has a column called `ID`
- `AppAreas` has a column called `ID`
- `UserClaimData` has a column called `ID`

Change the `Select *` to specify the columns of the tables you want to have on the View table, and put a particularry name, or just don't put them.

You need to change the name of some columns in the view. Use `AppAreas.ID as aaID`